# Where are books downloaded from Amazon Kindle app stored in Android?

Tags: kindle, android

I download a book from Amazon Kindle app to my Android 4.4.2 phone (Kyocera Hydro Icon), and would like to transfer it to my laptop. Where is it stored in my phone?

Is it possible to find it out using some download history of Android?

Is it possible to search the file (with guessed file name) in the file systems on my phone using some command or program?

Where is Amazon Kindle app stored? Can the book be stored in the same directory?

Answer (score 1):

The path should be something like "mnt/sdcard/android/data/com.amazon.kindle/files"

Just navigate to it with file manager of choice.

Download history won't be of help. 
App and it's data are usually stored in separate places.

Many file managers allow searching for a file, but most often then not it's a pain in the arse to do so. (With Root Browser, atleast)